# Natbib texmaker

Tags: latex, bibtex, texmaker

I am using following test program in texmaker

For e.g.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
  hello\citet*{greenwade93}
\bibliographystyle{plainat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

And the entry in bibliography is

```
@article{greenwade93,
author  = "George D. Greenwade",
title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
year    = "1993",
journal = "TUGBoat",
volume  = "14",
number  = "3",
pages   = "342--351",
year = "2004"
}
```

when i build bibtex and pdflatex then the output is just "hello?" (no errors/warning in texmaker). Then i ran "pdflatex test" it shows

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `greenwade93' on page 1 undefined on input lin
e 8.
```

And then "bibtex test" shows

```
I couldn't open style file plainat.bst
```

I checked in miktex package manager natbib package is installed, all 3 ntabib bst files are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.8\bibtex\bst\natbib` folder.

Comment: Does it work if you use \bibliographystyle{plain} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bst` file you want is called `plainnat`. Yours is missing an `n`. Try:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```